# Clearing A Report - Contribution Summary

Tags: civicontribute, civireport

I clicked on 'Contribution Details' report and it had a general list of names from my last time playing with it. I clicked on a specific name I wanted to do a report for and tweaked the settings to me needs. Now, I want to change just the contact ID for this report with the same settings. However, there does not appear to be a way to change the contact ID or go back to the original list of names. I want to know how I can clear the settings entirely and/or at least change the contact ID. I already checked the filters section and the contact ID is not listed here to change.

Basically, I am trying to print of the donation history for each of our board members, but I cannot seem to do this from their contact page so trying from this report.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written doesn't make sense to me as when I click on a name in the contribution detail report I am taken through to the contact's record not to a somewhere I can tweak report settings.

You also haven't stated what verion of CiviCRM you are using. The report UI changed dramatically in 4.6 so if you are using a version early than that these instruction won't apply.

Those aside, go to **Administer > Civireport > Create new Report from template** and select the **contribution details** report. Filter on the name of one of the board members and tweak the settings to show what you want.

Once you are happy with report, open the **title and format** tab to give you new report a name and then go to the **Access** tab to choose where to put in the navigation menu and control access if needed. Then click on the  **Create Report** button.

You now have a new report instance where changing the name filter will give you an individual report for each board member.

Aside: CiviCRM likes to use names rather than contact ids to identify contacts, perhaps this was a conscious decision not to reduce people to numbers.